# Download pdf with php

Tags: php

I'm tring to do a file download with php I have this code:

```
    $dompdf->render();
    $arquivo = $dompdf->output();
    $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "pdf");
    file_put_contents($tmp, $arquivo);
    rename($tmp, $tmp .= '.pdf');
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($nomeDoPdf));
    readfile($tmp);
    unset($tmp);
```

When it does the download and I open the file, it says it's not possible to open the file.

Comment: Do you actually need that temp file for something else? You could just write `echo $arquivo;` instead of `readfile($tmp);` and remove all that logic.

Comment: An exit instruction just after output the content is very recommendable. And unset($tmp) is unneeded, except if you mean unlink($tmp) to delete the file. But really yo don't need the file, as you just have its content in $arquivo var, you're writing and then reading the file uselessly.

Comment: It seems you are using DomPDF to create PDF and let user download. DomPDF has option to download using `$dompdf->stream('file.pdf', ['Attachment' => 1]);`. Is this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the download of PDF files via settings in the Apache configuration file .htaccess. The following entry always starts a download:

`AddType application/octet-stream .pdf`

Alternatively, the download can also be forced by setting the header in PHP like you. But you have a small mistake (the closing quotation mark):

In this line: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($nomeDoPdf));`

Try:

```php
$headerAttachment = '"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($nomeDoPdf) .'"';
echo '"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName .'"';
header( $headerAttachment );
```